# populate a table from another table including logging

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to populate a table from another table including logging.

For example there 2 tables **A** and **B**.

- Data should be copied from **B** to **A**
- There is one primary key called `id` in both tables.
- The script should update the matching rows if existing.
- The script should insert the missing rows from **B** if not found in table **A**

Data is expected to be around 800 k, having 15 columns.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. Consider that questions like "how to do this" without showing any attempt or effort are usually not welcome here.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you mean with "including logging", but to insert/update from one table to another, use `merge`:

```
merge into a 
using b on (b.id = a.id)
when matched then update 
   set col1 = b.col1, 
       col2 = b.col2
when not matched then insert (id, col1, col2)
values (b.id, b.col1, col2);
```

This assumes the PK is named `id` in both tables.

Comment: Almost the same answer in almost same time.

Comment: @_a_horse_with_no_name I bet he want to keep history in the target table. SCD in BI terminology :)

Comment: I dunno if he means about loggin and nologging that effects redo logs and performance https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5280714813869

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into tableA a
using tableB b
on (a.id = b.id)
when matched then update set
--list columns here
when not matched then insert
--list columns to insert here
;
```

800k shouldn't be too much to insert in one transaction. If it is too much you should use cursor with `bulk collect` and split merge in a few steps passing to `using` only part of data. How big `limit` set for `bulk collect` you need to test which gives optimal times.